# Android OpenGLES error: Resource deadlock would occur

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing a photo editor app with "blur tool" which allow user to blur photos. To achieve that, I draw another "blur layer" over original image, and use opacity/alpha to show blur points.

My shader code:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform float aRadius;
uniform vec2 aTouchPosition;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main() {
    float dist = distance(aTouchPosition, gl_FragCoord.xy);
    if(dist <= aRadius)
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);
}
```

Every time user touch, I put the points to an array, then put to shader:

```
protected void onDrawFrame() {
    if (textures == null) return;

    shader.useProgram();

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.uMVPMatrix, 1, false, mScratchMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.position);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(shader.position, COORDINATE_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, mCubeCoordArray);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.inputTextureCoordinate);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(shader.inputTextureCoordinate, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTexCoordArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < listCurrent.size(); i++) {
        PaintData.Position pos = listCurrent.get(i);
        GLES20.glUniform1f(shader.aRadius, pos.size);
        GLES20.glUniform2f(shader.touchPosition, pos.x, pos.y);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
    listCurrent.clear();

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.position);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.inputTextureCoordinate);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

When user touch to draw, it generate about 20-100 points according to the path long or short. It's still OK, but when user save & restore editing, I must restore a huge amount of points in a single frame (the first frame). Which cause error and crash my app.

> W/Adreno-GSL: : ioctl fd 115 code 0xc040094a
>   (IOCTL_KGSL_GPU_COMMAND) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would
>   occur
>
> W/Adreno-GSL: : panel.gpuSnapshotPath is
>   not set.not generating user snapshot

---

After some investigation, I see that:

- For each point it must draw entire screen (instead of a tiny blur point which it should be drawn).

  => How can I optimize this by only draw a part of the screen which the blur point need to show)
- After finish calling `onDrawFrame()` function the first time (which execute all `glDrawArrays()` with my blur points), my app lock & wait for 2 seconds to execute `mEgl.eglSwapBuffers(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface)` function, after that it crashed.

  => How can I optimize the swap function?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and stumbled upon answer #10 on [this](https://bugs.dolphin-emu.org/issues/10038) forum post.

It seems like there are too many commands queued per frame, which somehow causes the gpu to freeze. What fixed the issue for me was always calling [glFinish()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFinish.xhtml) (waiting until all previously queued commands have been executed) or [glFlush()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFlush.xhtml) (forcing the execution of queued commands) after a couple of GL calls.